# Discord.net Shards randomly disconnecting

Tags: discord.net

Im randomly getting the error: `A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task` and when that happens my shard were the error ocurred disconnects without reconnecting.

The problem seems to occur with all the commands. But there is only a small change of it actually occurring. Most of the time the error happens when someone uses the **[Color =](https://github.com/BramEsendam/Color-Chan/blob/master/ColorChan/Discord/Commands/ColorCommands/UserCommands/SetColorCommand.cs)** command because that's the most used command.

Im using Discord.net v2.0.0-beta. I switched to the beta because i was having the same issue with 1.0.2

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when something is running and your bot receives new messages. Your bot wants to process the command, but the previous task is still running so it has to wait for it to finish.

You can fix this by making your bot async. A good introduction to asynchronous programming can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).